# Acesso ao XMLHttpRequest foi bloqueado pela política do CORS

Tags: php, ajax

Estou fazendo um post desta forma;

```
$.post("_checa.php",
{
    inst: 'val'
}, function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Está funcionando normal se uso no http, mas, ao trocar para https, tenho o retorno:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.meusite.com.br/_checa.php' from origin 'https://meusite.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

No arquivo `_checa.php` deixei em branco para testar, e está retornando status `301`

Comment: Observa ali o `www`, está em um subdomínio diferente. Não tenho certeza, mas acho que subdomínios diferentes, mesmo estando no mesmo domínio, dão erro de cors

Comment: Achei, valeu mano. Meu `<base href="https://www.meusite.com.br/">` estava com www, daí só o removi